# Is the metric space c0 of sequences of real numbers converging to zero is isometric to the metric space $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems

Is the metric space c0 of sequences of real numbers converging to zero is isometric to the metric space $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$

To begin this proof do I need to show that:

1. c0 is complete in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$
2. take some subset of c0
3. make an assumption that every subset of a complete set is isometric?

If I'm wrong in some of the steps let me know!

Comment: Do you mean isometrically isomorphic or just isometric ?

Comment: Just isometric.

Answer (score 1):

A closed ball of positive radius in $c_0$ has no extreme points, but a closed ball of positive radius in $\ell^1$ has infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

[Previous answer was nonsense and has been expunged.  Here is a correct argument.]

If you don't know Mazur-Ulam, you can instead argue directly that in $\ell^1$, the sequences $(0)$ and $(\delta_1^i)$ have a unique midpoint at $(\frac{1}{2}\delta_1^i)$. (Here $\delta_j^i=1$ if $i=j$, $0$ otherwise).

In $c_0$, on the other hand, no two points have unique midpoint, since if $(a_i)\in c_0$ is a nonzero sequence with $|a_k|$ realizing the supremum, then there is some $j\neq k$ where $|a_j|<|a_k|$, and then $(\frac{a_i}{2}(1-\delta_j^i)+\frac{a_k}{2} \delta_j^i)$ will be an alternative midpoint between $(a_i)$ and $(0)$, provided $\frac{a_j}{a_k}\geq 0$, otherwise  $(\frac{a_i}{2}(1-\delta_j^i)-\frac{a_k}{2} \delta_j^i)$ is an alternative midpoint.  By translation invariance it follows that no two points have a unique midpoint.

Since having a unique midpoint is preserved under isometries, there can be no isometry between the spaces.

Comment: Isn't the distance between $\delta_1$ and $-\delta_k$ equal to $1$? But you can modify to $b=-\delta_1+\delta_k$, right?

Comment: @Jochen Thanks, you're completely right about the original argument, but the whole thing turned out to be flawed anyway, so it's been overhauled now.

Answer (score 0):

By the [Mazur-Ulam theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) every  isometry from a real normed space $V$ onto a real normed space $W$  is an affine transformation, i.e. $Tx=Ax+b,$ where $A$ is a bounded linear transformation. Thus $A$ is an isometric isomorphism from $V$ onto $W.$

We may apply the above to $V=c_0$ and  $W=\ell^1,$ sequences with real entries. If these  space were isometrically isomorphic the dual spaces would be isometrically isomorphic. But $c_0^*=\ell^1$ is separable while $(\ell^1)^*=\ell^\infty$ is not.

The similar argument can be applied to $V=c$ and $W=\ell^1,$ where the first space consists of convergent sequences with real terms. This time the unit balls in both spaces admit extreme points.

Comment: But if we are going for just isometric, would my train of thought be correct? Because I'm not really sure what @Robert Israel is trying to get at